# How do I add Google Maps on my site?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a form and I want to add a "select location" option.

How can I do this, and how can I place a pin as the selected location?

Comment: could we see some code? or more background? or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to consider using the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/), as [davek already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624833/how-add-google-map-on-site/2624856#2624856).

The following example may help you getting started. All you would need to do is to change the JavaScript variable `userLocation` with the location chosen by your users from the drop-down field you mention.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps API Demo</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body onunload="GUnload()"> 

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var userLocation = 'London, UK';

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
       geocoder.getLocations(userLocation, function (locations) {         
          if (locations.Placemark)
          {
             var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
             var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
             var east  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
             var west  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;

             var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), 
                                            new GLatLng(north, east));

             var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

             map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
             map.addOverlay(new GMarker(bounds.getCenter()));
          }
       });
    }
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

The above example would render a map like the one below:

[image: Render google map in based on selected location]

The map will not show if the [Google Client-side Geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding) cannot retreive the coordinates from the address.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/v3/). There's lots of information there and several examples:without knowing more about your environment/requirements it is difficult to be more specific.