# Get a map & street view from an adress in a PHP-variable!

Tags: google-maps

I have a PHP-variable called $go_Adress which contains the adress I need to get a map and a street view from. How do I do that? I have created an api-key but else I don't know how to do it!

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just answered [another question on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624833/how-add-google-map-on-site), and I think I can use the same example here.

The following example may help you getting started. All you would need to do is to change the JavaScript variable `userLocation` with the address you have in your php variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps API Demo</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body onunload="GUnload()"> 

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var userLocation = 'London, UK';

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
       geocoder.getLocations(userLocation, function (locations) {         
          if (locations.Placemark)
          {
             var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
             var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
             var east  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
             var west  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;

             var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), 
                                            new GLatLng(north, east));

             var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

             map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
             map.addOverlay(new GMarker(bounds.getCenter()));
          }
       });
    }
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

The above example would render a map like the one below:

[image: Render google map in based on selected location]

You would probably need to replace the static:

```
var userLocation = 'London, UK';
```

... with:

```
var userLocation = '<?php echo $go_Adress; ?>';
```

... as [Fletcher suggested in another answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624899/get-a-map-street-view-from-an-adress-in-a-php-variable/2624952#2624952)

Note that the map will not show if the [Google Client-side Geocoder](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding) cannot retreive the coordinates from the address. You may want to see how to handle this situation.

As for the API Key, you need to add it as a parameter to the `<script>` `src` that is calling the Maps API, as shown in the [The "Hello, World" of Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/introduction.html#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps).

---

**UPDATE:**

I am updating the above example to use the [Street View Panorama](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Streetview) object. I hope that the example is self-explanatory, and that it gets you going in the right direction:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps API Demo - Street View</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body onunload="GUnload()"> 

    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var userLocation = 'London, UK';

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
       geocoder.getLocations(userLocation, function (locations) {         
          if (locations.Placemark)
          {
             var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
             var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
             var east  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
             var west  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;

             var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), 
                                            new GLatLng(north, east));

             new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
                                     { latlng: bounds.getCenter() });
          }
       });
    }
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot from the above example:

[image: Google Maps API Demo - Street View]

---

**2nd UPDATE:**

You can enable both the street view and the map canvas, by "merging" the two examples above, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps API Demo - Street View with Map</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body onunload="GUnload()"> 

    <div id="pano" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></div> 
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var userLocation = 'London, UK';

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
       geocoder.getLocations(userLocation, function (locations) {         
          if (locations.Placemark)
          {
             var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
             var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
             var east  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
             var west  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;

             var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), 
                                            new GLatLng(north, east));

             var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

             map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
             map.addOverlay(new GMarker(bounds.getCenter()));

             new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"),
                                     { latlng: bounds.getCenter() })
          }
       });
    }
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot for street view with map:

[image: Google Maps API Demo - Street View with Map]

---

**3rd UPDATE**:

The Google Maps API does not have a direct method to link the movements of the street view with the map. Therefore this has to be handled manually. The following example makes the red marker draggable, and when dropped it moves the street view accordingly. In addition, each time the street view is updated, the marker is updated on the map as well.

To try this example, make sure that you insert the API Key in the `<script>` `src` parameters, and that you try it from the domain where you registered the key. Otherwise, it looks like the events do not work properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps API Demo - Street View with Map</title> 
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script> 
  </head> 
  <body onunload="GUnload()"> 

    <div id="pano" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></div> 
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 200px"></div> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var userLocation = 'Copenhagen, Denmark';

    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
       var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

       geocoder.getLocations(userLocation, function (locations) {         
          if (locations.Placemark)
          {
             var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
             var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
             var east  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
             var west  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;

             var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), 
                                            new GLatLng(north, east));

             var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

             map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), 14);

             map.addOverlay(new GStreetviewOverlay());

             var marker = new GMarker(bounds.getCenter(), { draggable: true });
             map.addOverlay(marker);                                

             var streetView = new GStreetviewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"));

             streetView.setLocationAndPOV(bounds.getCenter()); 

             GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(latlng) {
                streetView.setLocationAndPOV(latlng);
             });

             GEvent.addListener(streetView, "initialized", function(location) {
                marker.setLatLng(location.latlng);
                map.panTo(location.latlng);
             });
          }
       });
    }
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot of the above example:

[image: Google Maps API Demo - Street View with Map]

Getting the street view working nicely with the map could be the topic of another Stack Overflow question, as there are quite a few considerations to make.

Comment: Is it possible to create it so that you have both a google map AND a google street view and when you move forward on street view the map follws :) ?

Comment: That screenshot is great and it is what I want. If you can make the stuff mentioned above about making the map move with the street view would make you an oracle in my book :)

Comment: @Dennis: Hehe... Yes, that is not made directly available by the Maps API, but it is definitely possible by listening to a few events. Let me give it a try...

Comment: http://maps.google.dk/maps?f=q&source=embed&hl=da&geocode=&sll=55.676294,12.568116&sspn=0.155258,0.475845&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Copenhagen+City+Hall&layer=c&cbll=55.676166,12.569615&panoid=hA2uRa70SllTqxZVE0jlfA&cbp=11,164.67,,0,-10.36&ll=55.676166,12.569615&spn=0.000402,0.002602&z=19 << there is an example right here in the street view.. This is from our Capitol in Denmark - Copenhagen.. :)

Comment: You are an oracle :) thank you VERY much :)
May you be blessed!

Comment: One more question - is it possible to make so you can zoom in/out on the map and not just in the streetview :) ?

Comment: @Daniel brilliant answer thanks. What is the code for showing a custom marker? I currently use this within staticmap url: &markers=icon:http://ourwebsite.com.au/demos/422/staticmap/images/mapMarker422.png , just not sure how to add it to your code????

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include a javascript file which uses the GClientGeocoder object as in this example:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding_Object

The javascript will need to be passed through a PHP interpreter which injects the address into a javascript variable.

So, for the above example

```
var myAddress = '<?php echo $go_Adress; ?>';
showAddress(myAddress);
```

But first I recommend getting a very basic map shown.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/introduction.html

Comment: I have this map and it all works with Daniel's code.. The problem now is to get a Street View box of the same address shown - how do I do that??

Comment: @Dennis: I've updated my answer, adapting the original example to render a Street View Panorama. I hope it will help you getting you started.