# Google Maps : Show Map Via Address

Tags: google-maps

I have this Code To show map on a page

```
var _map = new GMap2($get("gmap"));
var _latLng = new GLatLng(lat, lng);
_map.setCenter(_latLng, 11);
_map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
_map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
var _icon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
var marker = new GMarker(_latLng);
_map.addOverlay(marker);
```

But I do Not have GeoCode for Some Address.
How can I show Map via Address Only.

Answer (score 4):

You use the [`GeoCoder`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder) to get the address into latitude and longitude first, and then use that.

[Here's an example of how to geocode an address](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#Geocoding).

Comment: +1: Here's another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624833/how-do-i-add-google-maps-on-my-site