# Google maps with Mysql in Java EE framework

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, google-maps, jakarta-ee

I am working on a web application with Java EE that takes the address of people from a MySql database and shows their location on Google maps.

Currently I am doing it manually as I don't know how to do integration of Google maps in JSP. Kindly give me some sort of direction to do so with Java.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, fetch list of all addresses from the database, then using Google geocoder service, fetch the latitude-longitude of those addresses. Here is the sample code (http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples/source/browse/trunk/geocoder/java/GeocodingSample.java?r=2476). Then you can create Google Map Marker on the map..Here is the sample code http://www.paulwest.co.uk/article.php/using-google-maps-api-to-mark-your-location-and-address

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Yogesh - please go through this question. It will solve half of your concerns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875479/google-maps-show-map-via-address

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a servlet should be used. This servlet gets data from the database and converts it to json format.

And using ajax, the json data are taken and then Google map JavaScript API is used.

Answer (score 0):

hey guys this code helped finaaly did it feeling very happy thanks a lot ::

```
<sql:setDataSource var="enterdata" 
                driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
                user="root" password="root" 
                url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/enterdata" />
            <sql:query var="list" dataSource="${enterdata}" 
            sql= "SELECT * from cropdata where FarmerName=\"${param.FarmerName}\"" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?      sensor=false"></script>


           <script type="text/javascript">

var markers = [<c:forEach var="s" items="${list.rows}">
    ['Farmer Name :${s.FarmerName}<br>Crop Type:${s.CropName}',${s.Latitude},${s.longitude}],
            </c:forEach>        
];



function initializeMaps() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0][1],markers[0][2]);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    mapTypeControl: false
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
}
```